# AngularJS: how to make all ng-model be string. JavaScript and long integers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing an angularjs app and I'm having that old javascript problem with long integers. E.g: in the text box I type `76561198041811759` and `76561198041811760` is the value of my `$scope` property when I send my requests to the server.

I would like to know if there is a way to force angularjs read all `ng-models` as string.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather than reading them as string. you should consider performing cast on model fields before sending them off to server.

eg

```
$scope.sendToServer($scope.number + '');
```

my understanding of this model-view binding thing is that, you should keep your model as close as possible to the actual view. When your model is taken out of the model-view context, and is sent to server, I would consider it as a data-transfer-object (dto).

domain object > data transfer object > view models can be similar or even identical, but they server different purposes